# why we use drop_first in dummies?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

guys im currently working on dataframe with pandas and for data preparation i was use get_dummies and dummies has a keyword argument (drop_first)

I knew drop first is removing first level of categorical but why we should remove that ?

```
pd.get_dummies(df[SigCat], drop_first = True)
```

Comment: and sorry about english :)

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28353/always-drop-the-first-column-after-performing-one-hot-encoding

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming, but about statistical modeling theory.